# How to delete unneeded element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function:

```js
const validateInput = event => {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/,.e+-/g, '');
};
```

This is the way I use the function: `onKeyUp={validateInput}`

It deletes unnecessary elements and deletes everything I put in the input what I don't need. How to correct it?

Comment: Your input component should use the setState or hooks to change the input value, and not access to the event object.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. What do you want to happen exactly? "Elements" has a specific meaning in HTML/DOM, but it seems like what you actually want to do is delete certain characters from the `value` of an input element? Input elements can't contain other elements as children.

Comment: Yes, I mean characters. I need this characters ,.e+- to be deleted the moment I type them into input or it must be restricted to type them at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a state and use it as a value for your input.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const validateInput = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.value.replace(/[,.e+-]/g, "");
    console.log(text);
    setValue(text);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Value: {value}</h1>
      <input value={value} onChange={validateInput} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit determined-hill-v8m6x]